# Get user input in a assembly boot loader

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bootloader, bios

I want to create a assembly bootloader and get user input. I have created a boot loader which boots again if I press any key on my keyboard. But how can I create a bootloader which reboots if I e. g. press the button r.

Comment: You can read user input using the BIOS function [`int 10h, ah=00h`](http://www.techhelpmanual.com/229-int_16h_00h__read__wait_for__next_keystroke.html).  Then compare the key pressed by the user with whatever key you look out for.

Comment: I'm guessing you're talking about a PC-compatible x86 booting in legacy BIOS mode?  I added tags for that.  If you actually have an ARM board or something, please retag appropriately.

Comment: @fuz: You mean int 16h, not 10h.

Comment: @ecm Indeed!  I even linked the right page.  Have been programming so much INT10-related stuff these days and just slipped.

Comment: I am booting in x86 real mode and how do I use ah=00h?

Comment: @Tentaquod Set AH to 0 and then issue an `int 16h` instruction.  Afterwards, AL contains the next ASCII character that was typed.